# How do i stop System.out.printf to stop giving me error in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am very new to java programing, and I am learning everything trough the book introduction to java programing by Y.Danniel Liang, and as much as I have tried to find an answer I simply dont understand what is hapenning...therefore your help would be very welcomed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class areaOfPentagon {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the lenght of center to the vertex : ");

    double r = input.nextDouble();

    double s = 2*r*(Math.sin(Math.PI/5));

    double area = 5*(Math.pow(s, 2))/(4*(Math.tan(Math.PI/5)));

    System.out.printf("the area %4.2f of the pentagon is", area);
```

Comment: The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, double) this is the error

Comment: Please check the duplicate Q/A where this issue is covered and solved.

Comment: thank you i have sorted the issue... I had my config set to 1.4 on eclipse....